# How to accept PL/SQL indexed table in Java?

Tags: java, database, oracle, plsql, resultset

I have a `Oracle` function written in my `database` package which returns me the bulk collected `PL/SQL` indexed table. I searched a lot but not yet found a way to accept the same into java, some references say accept it into `Array` and some says `String`. My java call for the same is:

```
    ResultSet rs;
    stmt=dcc.con.prepareCall("{? = call PACKAGE_NAME.FUNCTION_NAME(?)}");
            stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.PLSQL_INDEX_TABLE);
    stmt.setInt(2, 5);
    rs = stmt.execute();
```

My question is what datatype in Java supports this? How do I accept it and iterate through the same in Java?

My function in Oracle for the same is:

```
FUNCTION FUNCTION_NAME(p_NoOfDays IN PLS_INTEGER)
    RETURN TABLE_OF_MYTABLE 
    IS P_Table TABLE_OF_MYTABLE;
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    BULK COLLECT INTO P_Table FROM MYTABLE  
    WHERE SOMEDATE<= SYSDATE 
    AND SOMEDATE>=SYSDATE-p_NoOfDays
    ORDER BY SOMEDATE;
    FOR index IN 1 .. P_Table .COUNT
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(P_Table (indexlog).SOMECOLUMN);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN P_Table ;
END FUNCTION_NAME;
```